# Setup Autologon with C# for Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp

I'm trying to figure out how to setup the autologon process in WindowsXP from C#.  Please note, I am aware of the registry keys that can be used.  This is for a domain however, to autologon generic IDs.  By using the DefaultPassword registry key, user can see the passwords to the generic IDs, and this is very unsecure.  I'm trying to figure out the method to do this the way one would via userpasswords2 control item.  We have a system in place already, but we need to make changes to it, and it was previously written using PrimalScript, and compiled to exe - and the source code was on a laptop we no longer have access to.

Comment: Question..? do you use anything like ActiveDirectory, I've done this successfully in the past however I am against the autologin in some aspects vs other i.e Winforms vs Web Forms

Comment: Are you just trying to mimic what your PrimalScript app did, or are you asking about the right way to do this in C#?